# Worklight server with LTPAAuthentication request login for all applications

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-security

I've set my **authenticationConfig.xml** to work with LTPAAuthentication in this way:
[image]

It works well with application where i require LTPA Authentication.
But there are some apps deployed on the WL Console that not need any authentication, they just call adapters. From browser (PReview common resource) they work as well as before, but if i run them from my android i get those error on **Logcat**:

[image]

...................................... (all the login.html page)

[image]

It returns me the entire **login.html** page as it does with application that requires LTPA mobile test, here you can see the **application-descriptor.xml** that highlight no need of **security tests**:
[image]

Any suggestion?

EDIT: this is the adapter, it doesn't require security tests
[image]

Comment: That means that you do not have the LTPA token, so you have to login again, but the application is not expecting that it has to log in again, so it does not know what to do with it. 

Do you have the LTPA challenge handler in your application? Please verify this because I suspect that you do not and that is why it does not know how to handle LTPA.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your response.
Maybe i didn't explain well what is my problem.
When i need that my application use the login through the WASLTPA system i can use it without problem, just put a securityTest in my application-descriptor.xml

The problem is for applications that do not require any login so they never obtain a LTPA Token. It seems that with this kind of authenticationConfig.xml i always need to put a login in my application for obtaining the token. I hust want the this kind of applications remain not "secure".

Comment: Do you have security tests defined for the procedures in your adapter descriptor?

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you have an adapter that you have protected using WASLTPA security that you want to be accessible by all devices regardless of whether or not they have been authenticated by the WASLTPARealm. I think the solution is to re-design how your security and adapters behave.

If you wish for an adapter to be called from an application that does not need to be authenticated, then don't protect the adapter using a security realm. If being logged into the WASLTPARealm is not a requirement for accessing the resources that this adapter is exposing, then there is no point in using the realm to protect it.

For the apps that do require login, you should separate the authentication logic from the adapter calls. You can still require the client to login in order to use the app and call adapters without having to protect the adapter with the security test. There are APIs to check if a user is logged in and to prompt them to login to a realm. You don't have to use the challenge sent back from adapter to prompt a login.

An adapter should be protected by a security test only if being logged into that realm defined by the security test is a requirement for using that adapter. From reading your post, it does not seem to be a requirement.

```
From browser (PReview common resource) they work as well as before, but if i run them from my android i get those error on Logcat
```

I have a strong feeling that in your browser you have an LTPA token which is why this is working from an app that hasn't logged in to the LTPA realm. Try clearing your cookies and trying to do this again to confirm.

Comment: Thank you jnortey.
For the browser you were right, the LTPA token was already set so it was working.
But the adapter never require any security test, but it's still inaccessible from app that doesn't require login.

Comment: Then this is because your server's entire WAR file is protected using global security. This means that any request made to your server is going to require an LTPA token, regardless of whether it is going to worklight or anything else on your server. Your options are to either require LTPA authentication for every request, or disable global authentication on your WAS server and only require authentication for specific resources on the worklight WAR. This is referred to as "Option 2" in the LTPA documentation.